# Who uses sequence diagram in project team?

Tags: uml, sequence, diagram

In project team, who is the responsible of drawing up sequence diagram (UML 2.0) and who uses it after?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone who is designing the architecture of the project would be assigned to design the sequence diagram. The duty can be assigned to various team members depending on the dynamics of the software house, the stake holders involved and depending on the seriousness of the project.

To add to this, a developer, tester, team leader, CTO would be using the diagram at the time of the development cycle. Moreover, the management and even the client would/can use it to check how the project is proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence diagram models the flow of you logic.
So anyone who want's to model some workflow or some program/test logic can/should draw it and everyone who want's to implement the logic should use it afterwards.

For example it might be useful to make a sequence diagram to model a certain part of your application, generate or write a test from the diagram, implement the logic and see if it still conforms to the tests you generated/written earlier, which should be equivalent to the sequence diagram.

Comment: Thanks! I liked the mentioned point about workflow !